# How to remove search feature in inputComboboxListOfValues?

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm working on `Jdeveloper` version `11.1.1.7.0.` I am using component 'inputComboboxListOfValues'.

For my requirement I do not need the query feature and do not want a link like 'more' or 'search' to appear in the drop down list. Can I remove this search option?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not familiar with this component, I searched online. By reading the doc, I guess there is no style attribute to let you simply turn off the search option, but according to this discussion on the oracle forum:

https://community.oracle.com/message/4304673#4304673

It seems you can do some skinning for your component to hide the search option...but I haven't tried it yet.

There is also a link for skinning:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/skin-selectors.html
Then search "af:inputComboboxListOfValues".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for your jdev version but it works on 11.2.3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abwpk.png

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the Search capability for the LOV is done at the View/Attribute level (Select Attribute/List Of Values / UI Hints / Include Search Region = No Search)

Answer (score -1):

set "readOnly=true".
  --Peddi

Answer (score -1):

Did you try and set styleclass="noSearch" it should work.